# JavaScript/jQuery .click() issue with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click, fadeto

I'm doing The Odin Project's JavaScript/jQuery project in its Web Development 101 course. I am building an "etch a sketch" app using divs as squares on a grid that change color when the mouse passes over them. For my final option, I would like to leave a trail of fading blocks. This works when I press my button. HOWEVER, when I select a different option, after selecting the "Leave a trail" one, the trail of fading divs automatically is added to the others as well. I need to know if there is a way to end the function once a different button is pressed. Also, I'm a beginner and am just learning this language and framework. Thank you in advance!

```
$(".trail").click(function() {
    $(".grid").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 0);
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(600, 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should remove the handler from the grid once another button is clicked like `$(".grid").off('mouseenter')`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the mouseenter handler from the grid element once another button is clicked, so something like

```
$(".trail").click(function() {
    $(".grid").on('mouseenter.trail', function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 0);
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(600, 1);
        });
    });
});
```

then in other button clicks, you can remove this handler using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off)

```
$(".grid").off('mouseenter.trail')
```

The namespaces are used in the event registration and removal so that by mistake we don't remove any other handlers

Comment: That makes total sense! Thank you so much!